# Subclassed Image to add text but image hides it

Tags: fabricjs

I've subclassed the Image class so that I can add a label to it. However, the text seems to get rendered before the image such that the image is hiding the label. Below is the class declaration. Note that I tried calling callSuper() at the end of the _render() method, which didn't make sense to me anyway, and it didn't work. Seems to me if super is called first and then text is added after it should be on top right?

```
    var Cabinet = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Image, {

    type: 'cabinet',

    initialize: function(element, options) {
        options || (options = { });

        this.callSuper('initialize', element, options);
        this.set('label', options.label || '');
        this.set('height', options.height || 48);
        this.set('width', options.width || 24);
    },

    toObject: function() {
        return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper('toObject'), {
            label: this.get('label')
        });
    },

    _render: function(ctx) {
        this.callSuper('_render', ctx);

        var txtOffset = this.label.length * 6;

        ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
        if (this.get('angle') !== 0) {
            ctx.font = '11px Arial Narrow';

            //ctx.save();
            ctx.rotate(90 * Math.PI/180);
            ctx.fillText(this.label, (this.width / 2) - (txtOffset / 2) - 8, this.height - 10);
            //ctx.restore();

        } else {
            ctx.font = "9px Arial Narrow";
            ctx.fillText(this.label, (this.width / 2) - (txtOffset / 2) - 8, this.height - 10);
        }
    }
 });
```

I would appreciate any help you can provide.

Thanks,
Rob